# React - ref Value In onChange in map() That Generate <table> (Meteor)

Tags: reactjs

here is a snippet from render()

```
{users.map((user)=>{
    return <tr key={user._id}>
        <td><input  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, user._id)}
            type="text" 
            ref="name" 
            value={user.profile.firstName} />
        </td>
    </tr>
})}
```

here is the handler:

```
handleChange(userId) {
    console.log(userId);
    var name = this.refs.name.value.trim();
    console.log(name);
}
```

The handler will print the correct userId but always the last name in the user table

What is the correct way to create a handler that can fetch the values of the specific input field in a table created by map?

Should I generate unique refs somehow?

Or is there a different method for this one?

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` receives a [`SyntheticEvent`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.26.0/lib/react.js#L266) as a parameter as well. If you add that to your `onChange` handler, you can inspect the target and get the new value:

handleChange:

```
handleChange(userId, event) {
    console.log(userId);
    var inputElement = event.target;
    console.log(inputElement.name + ': ' + inputElement.value);
}
```

To handle many inputs in a single `handleChange`, add standard [`name` attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) to the inputs and inspect them in the change handler:

```
{users.map((user)=>{
    return <tr key={user._id}>
        <td><input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, user._id)}
            name="name"
            type="text"
            value={user.profile.firstName} />
        </td>
    </tr>
})}
```

This is covered in the [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) docs.

Comment: I thought about this but this it is a simplified code, in the reality I have a number of fields (refs) that I need to collect thus this solution is not good enough

Comment: Are you routing all change events through a single handler? I suggest adding standard [`name` attributes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) to each input and doing work depending on the name of the given input.

Comment: I updated the code to use `name` attributes. This will keep your form closer to a regular old HTML form that is submittable via a standard POST and prevent the need for many React-specific `ref` attrs.

Answer (score 0):

Create new component UserListRow.jsx move the code there, e.g.:

```
                    {users.map((user)=>{
                        return <UserListRow user={user} key={user._id}/>
                    })}
```

UserListRow.jsx render:

```
return <tr key={user._id}>
        <td><input  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, user._id)}
            type="text" 
            ref="name" 
            value={user.profile.firstName} />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

move `handleChange` to UserListRow.jsx

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using the index. You can create an object containing the information you want to update and the item index and set this object on state. Then, on input's value you make a verification between the item index and the object's index you set on state.

here follows and example in typescript and hooks.

```
interface userNameState {
  index: number;
  name: string;
}

const [userName, setUserName] = useState({} as userNameState);
```

the handle change function.

```
function handleChange(e: FormEvent, index: number) {
    let enterEvt = e.target as HTMLButtonElement

    const userName = {
      index: index,
      title: enterEvt.value
    }
    setUserName(userName)
}
```

and the map function would something like that

```
{users.map((user, index)=>{
    return <tr key={user._id}>
        <td>
          <input  
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
            type="text"
            value={userName.index === index ? userName.name : user.name} />
        </td>
    </tr>
})}
```